# Yii2 optimizing long running queries to lower timeouts

Tags: php, yii2

Am trying to fetch over 10000 records with a query but keep on getting timeouts

```
   $from ="2018-06-20 23:59";
    $to ="2018-06-28 00:00";
    //generate nairobi plant excell data
    $query = NaiTblTrucks::find()
        ->leftJoin('tbl_truck_history', 'tbl_truck_history.truck_id = tbl_trucks.id')
        //->where(['tbl_trucks.town' => 1])
        ->leftJoin('tbl_security_trucks', 'tbl_security_trucks.truck_id = tbl_trucks.id')
        ->andWhere(['IN', 'tbl_truck_history.status', [1]])
        ->andWhere(['NOT IN', 'tbl_trucks.truck_status', [13,6]])
        ->orderBy(['tbl_security_trucks.time_out' => SORT_DESC]);

    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'OR',
        ['IN',  'tbl_trucks.material',3]
    ]);

    $query->andWhere(['between', 'tbl_security_trucks.time_out', strtotime($from), strtotime($to)]);
```

Now am using the dataprovider to return results, like

```
 $data = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'sort' => ['defaultOrder' => ['created_at' => SORT_DESC]],
        'pagination' =>false
    ]);
```

From the dates above from and to the data expected can be very large, that is a day can have over 1000 records.
I have also tried paginating the requests by

```
    $totalrecords = $data->getTotals()//dataprovider get totals
    $gotcount = 0;
    $currentpage = 0;
    $fetched = [];

    for ($val= 0; $val<=$totalrecords;){
        $fetchedata = $this->getTrucks($query,10,$currentpage);
        array_push($fetched,$fetchedata);
        $gotcount += count($fetchedata);
        $val +=10;
        $currentpage += 1;
    }

 public function getTrucks($query, $pagesize, $currentPage){
    $data = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'sort' => ['defaultOrder' => ['created_at' => SORT_DESC]],
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 100,
            'page' => 0
        ],
    ]);

    return $data->getModels();

     }
```

but both the above tries still give me timeouts. By reducing the dates to a day am able to get the data.How do i optimize this further to ensure that i dont get timeouts. Are there better ways of doing this especially when handling large datasets.

Later after fetching this data am exporting this to excell with php spreadsheets .

Comment: 10000 record  via ActiveRecord  is very slow  .. you should eval a raw query and access  the result directly by array ..

Comment: `ActiveRecord` is never a recommended approach when working with bulk records either `inserting` or `selecting` both will be effected,  use the `yii\db\Query` to crete your queries. and run them